# distinct & trim in JPA with hibernate 3.2.6

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa

Is there a way to do select  distinct trim(addressInfo.city) in JPA ?

I got this error (without the trim it works fine)

```
Caused By: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

>

and Here the generated SQL:

```
select distinct trim(addressinf3_.city) as col_0_0_ 
    from t_application applicatio0_ 
    left outer join t_user user1_ on applicatio0_.first_signatory=user1_.id 
    left outer join t_company company2_ on user1_.company=company2_.id 
    left outer join t_address_info addressinf3_ on company2_.address=addressinf3_.id 
where applicatio0_.discriminator='SERVICE' and (addressinf3_.city is not null) order by addressinf3_.city
```

Comment: What Hibernate version are you using? And what type is `addressInfo.city`? This works for me on Hibernate 4.3 `select distinct trim(u.firstName) from User u`

Comment: 3.2.6, maybe that's why

Comment: Turn on SQL logging and check what is the actual query that is being generated.

Comment: And please post the whole query you are executing, is there a `order by` statement in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This exception](https://support.software.dell.com/toad-for-oracle/kb/68954) usually happens when you have some column/expression in `order by` clause which you don't have in `select` clause, in combination with `distinct`. Without knowing the actual JPQL query you are executing, here is an example that should work

```
select distinct trim(addressInfo.city) 
from AddressInfo addressInfo 
where <some conditions> 
order by trim(addressInfo.city)
```

If you use `trim(addressInfo.city)` in `select`, then you must use it also in `order by`. Without `trim` it won't work.